# Run "Invoke-Expression" statement as another user

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have a PowerShell script/function, that takes few arguments and runs it.

```
Invoke-Expression ".\ScriptFile.ps1 $($Node.Name).xml C:\TempFolder\ $($Node.Name) local"
```

Now I want to run that as another user.

`Invoke-Expression` doesn't have an inherent parameter `credential` that facilitates this. On the other hand `Invoke-Command` has a `Credential` (`Get-Credential`) parameter that facilitates running as another user. I tried replacing `Invoke-Expression` with `Invoke-Command` with no luck.

How do I tackle this to run the above expression as another user?

Structure of Script Resource.

```
Script Deploy
        {       
            SetScript =     
@"             
                Set-Location D:\Deploy
                Invoke-Expression ".\ScriptFile.ps1 $($Node.Name).xml C:\TempFolder\ $($Node.Name) local"                                               
"@

            TestScript = 
            {
                return $false            
            }
            GetScript = {
                return @{   
                        GetScript = $GetScript
                        SetScript = $SetScript
                        TestScript = $TestScript
                    }
            }
            DependsOn = "[File]CopyMe"
        }
```

P.S.: All this happens inside a SetScript of `Script` User in Desired State Configuration.

Comment: Define "with no luck". What did your `Invoke-Command` statement look like? Did you get an error?

Comment: This is my error message `PowerShell provider MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message:
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Comment: Please update your question with the **`Invoke-Command` statement** and the **complete error message**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Invoke-Command` can indeed be used to run a script on the local machine as a different user (as @mjolinor said, it will be a different session). You must have powershell remoting enabled (which you almost certainly do if you're using DSC). The command would look like this (assuming a translated version of your above invocation):

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential $cred -File .\ScriptFile.ps1 -ArgumentList "$($Node.Name).xml","C:\TempFolder",$Node.Name,"local"
```

I suspect that this will not solve your problems though. The error message in your comment is just a generic error, it means something went wrong. To get more a clue, you should have a look at the [xDscDiagnostics PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xDscDiagnostics-PowerShell-abb6bcaa) to aid in troubleshooting.

What would be great though, is if you could tell us what you're ultimately trying to do. What does .\ScriptFile.ps1 *actually do*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  In order to run the command under a different security context you must do it in a session that's running under those credentials.

If you look at the parameter sets of Invoke-Command, the Credential parameter is only available in parameter sets that specify another computer or URI (which will result in creating a new session).  The FilePathRunspace and InSession parameter sets will cause the command to be invoked in the local session, and don't have a Credential parameter.

Likewise, Invoke-Command is going to run the command in the local session and doesn't have a Credential parameter, because you can't change the security context once it's established for the session.